# Each recipient in the signing order must be unique error

Tags: docusignapi

I want to set up a template with two recipients with the same role name but different names and email addresses. I also want the signing order and tabs to be the same for those two recipients. I notice that the Docusign UI will try to change the name and email inputs, so they match and throw a 'Each recipient in the signing order must be unique' error when I try to save the template. Example where the emails were automatically changed:
[image]

However, I was able to create my desired setup via the Docusign API, so I'm wondering if there's something I'm not quite understanding about recipients and how they are uniquely identified. I also tried looking through the Docusign documentation and didn't see anything that described what I'm looking for. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Many thanks!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role names must be unique in a template.

You can have `Buyer1` and `Buyer2` roles.

Remember that fields (tabs) are owned by roles. So each recipient (role) needs a unique name. The tabs for each role can be the same, but it will be two sets of tabs (one per role), not two roles sharing one set of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

So, see at the top-left corner of your screenshot where there's an unchecked box that says "Set signing order"?

If you check that, it will allow you to have an order, and have these two recipients have different values (1, 2, etc.) for the order.

This is probably what you did from the API where you didn't get the error.

The rule is this - if two recipients have the same email address, they must have different signing order, or else you get an error.

Comment: I tried adding the routing order as suggested but the UI still will not allow me to add two separate recipients with the same role name ('Buyer') but different names and emails. Is that not a supported scenario?

Comment: If you are using a template and the template has the roles defined, you need to check the template. I think maybe in this case your template roles have the same routing order.